# How can I use many targetEntity in Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two table:

**Event.orm.yml**

```
manyToOne:
    last_author:
        targetEntity: User
        inversedBy: last_author_contact
        joinColumn:
            name: last_author_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

**User.orm.yml**

```
oneToMany:
    last_author_contact:
        targetEntity: Event
        mappedBy: last_author
```

Now I want add new "Project" entity which connected with "User" entity.
So I must write in **User.orm.yml**:

```
oneToMany:
        last_author_contact:
            targetEntity: Event
            mappedBy: last_author
        last_author_project_contact:
            targetEntity: Project
            mappedBy: last_author_project
```

And create **Project.orm.yml**:

```
manyToOne:
        last_author_project:
            targetEntity: User
            inversedBy: last_author_project_contact
            joinColumn:
                name: last_author_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

How can I use many targetEntity and can not write similar code in User entity (setters and getters)?

Like this:

```
oneToMany:
    last_author_contact:
        targetEntity: Event
        targetEntity: Project
        mappedBy: last_author
```